# Creation of Arrays in Java (The C++ Style)

Tags: java, c++, arrays

Why can't we make arrays in Java like this:

```
int marks[5];
```

And assign values after this declaration?

Anyone please explain the terminology or difference.

Comment: Did you try? What where the results?

Comment: Can you flesh out your question, it seems like you are asking "Why doesn't Java use the exact same syntax as C++?" It's possibly just me, the question may make more sense to people who know C++ & Java rather than just Java.

Comment: @Tichodroma: he probably tried and the result was "Syntax error on token "5", delete this token".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is because there are no stack arrays in Java. Here is Java equivalent:

```
int[] marks = new int[5];
```

It looks a lot like allocating dynamically-sized arrays in C++. Of course you don't have to worry about calling a `delete[]`, because it's garbage collected.

Answer (score 13):

Because the syntax you're citing allocates the array on the stack, and Java arrays are objects, and all Java objects are allocated on the heap (modulo recent JVM optimizations, but those are implicit).

And it pretty much has to be that way in a language without manual memory management because stack-allocated stuff disappears when the call returns, leading to dangling pointers, and a fundamental feature of Java is not to allow stuff like that.

Of course one could argue that Java should use the stack allocation syntax to do heap allocation, but that would have confused the heck out of anyone who knew C - not good.

Answer (score 5):

In Java the size of the array is determined by the expression that creates it, e.g.:

```
int[] marks = new int[5];
```

or

```
int[] marks = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

---

***Note also*** that although the syntax `int marks[]` is allowed in Java (Java has several such rules for compatibility with C++), it is not recommended, the syntax `int[] marks` is more idiomatic and thus preferred.

Answer (score 3):

```
int[] marks = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
```

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to remove the 5.

Answer (score 1):

Because arrays are `Object`-s (inheriting from the `Object` class). And to create an object you have to use the `new` keyword. (Most of the time).
I think the reason behind the `new` keyword is to denote that the variables are references to dynamically allocated instances.

Comment: Okay...Getting some of it now...Thanks